# Html.TextBoxFor set value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use `<input type="file" id="fileId" name="fileId"/>` and
        `<% = Html.TextBoxFor (x => x.FileName, new {@ class = "className", maxlength = 255, id = "fileName"})%>` in my mvc project. I want to save in a text box the file name selected in the INPUT element. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use javascript to achieve this. Here's an example with jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#fileId').change(function() {
        // When the user selects a file, read the selected filename
        // and set it to the textbox
        var filename = $(this).val();
        $('#fileName').val(filename);
    });
});
```